# Having trouble making this program (Classes)

Tags: python, class

I am told to write a class containing the following fields:

- id: This is the id of the customer
- first_name: This the first name of the customer
- last_name: This is the last name of the customer
- address: this is the entire address
- monthly_expenses: this is a list of the monthly expenses

Additionally, I am told to add the following methods (This is the step I'm confused about):

- get_id: This method returns the value of the id field.
- get_expenses: This method returns the list of expenses stored.
- get_average_expense: This method returns the average of all expenses stored in the    monthly_expenses field.
- get_max: This method returns the highest expense stored in the _ _monthly_expenses field
- get_lowest: This method returns the lowest expense stored in the _ _monthly_expenses field

Here is the code I have so far:

```
class customer:

    def __init__(self, studentID, first_name, last_name, address, monthly_expense):

        self.__id=14587

        self.__first_name=Alexandra

        self.__last_name=Lopez

        self.__address=63 North Corona Lane  Glen Cove, NY 11542

        self.__monthly_expenses=[230.71, 212.57, 360.64, 292.44]

    def get_id(self):
        return self.__id

    def get_name1(self):
        return self.__name1

    def get_name2(self):
        return self.__name2

    def get_house(self):
        return self.__house

    def get_expense(self):
        return self.__expense



    def __str__(self):
        print("Customer ID:",self.__id)
        print("Name:",self.__name1, self.__name2)
        print("Address:", self.__house)
        print("Monthly Expenses:", self.__expense)
```

Lastly, here is the sample output I am given:

```
Customer ID: 14587
Name: Alexandra Lopez
Address: 63 North Corona Lane  Glen Cove, NY 11542
Monthly Expenses: [230.71, 212.57, 360.64, 292.44]
Average Expense: 274.09
Highest Expense: 360.64
Lowest Expense: 212.57
```

Id appreciate any help I can get. I'm pretty stuck here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure where the problem is but I see you're missing the max, min and avg functions 
there's a python max(list) function same for the min(list) for

```
def get_max(self): 
    return max(self.__monthly_expenses)

def get_lowest(self):
    return min(self.__monthly_expenses)
```

for the average you can sum the array and divide by length [example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-average-list-python/)